# Replace c style for-loop in Swift 2.2.1

Tags: ios, swift

This is the loop in my app:

```
for var i = column - 1; i >= 0 && burgers[i, row]?.burgerType == burgerType;
        i -= 1, horzLength += 1 {

}
```

**What would be the best way to implement this loop in Swift 2.2.1?**

Comment: Do you mutate `i` or `horzLength` inside the loop body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var i = column - 1
while i >= 0 && burgers[i, row]?.burgerType == burgerType {
    i -= 1
    horzLength += 1
}
```

This sort of abuse of the `for` loop syntax was the  exact reason it was deprecated in Swift 2.2. Even if a `for` syntax was available, this would still be more clear than that abomination